# Official description of purpose of @angular/platform-server?

Tags: node.js, angular, package.json

I'm just reviewing some dependencies of an angular project.

During that, I had to figure out, that I couldn't find any description for the single angular sub packages describing their purpose.

Example:

- `@angular/platform-server`

When browsing to the API documentation or the npm package page, there is literally no description explaining the purpose of those packages:

- https://angular.io/api/platform-server
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/platform-server
- https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/packages/platform-server
- https://angular.io/guide/npm-packages#feature-packages

I think this where all the official sources. But no word about `@angular/platform-server` lost.

Is there any official documentation which includes this? Or does this simply not exist? I don't want to have tons of packages in my dependencies of which I have no idea of what they do and if I need them at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why angular packages are separated and why we need them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45230638/why-angular-packages-are-separated-and-why-we-need-them)

Comment: This post is leading to this link https://angular.io/guide/npm-packages#feature-packages which contains an incomplete list of package descriptions. `@angular/platform-server` is not mentioned in any way.

Comment: I assume someone voted this down due to it being a question asking for off-site documentation. I think common sense suggests this question is an exception to that so im up-voting.

Comment: @Stu two things: 1. given that it *does* ask for off-site resources it's not clear how you think it's an exception; 2. please don't vote on the basis of disagreement with the reason you invented for someone else's vote, follow the guidance on the tooltips (see e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311406/is-using-an-up-vote-to-balance-out-a-down-vote-wrong).

Comment: If it's that specific package you're interested in, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40223442/whats-the-main-purpose-of-platform-server-module-in-angular-2

Comment: Yes this is about the same issue. The answer is just not really sufficient. StackOverflow is obviously not an official documentation for a product.

Comment: If there is an existing question you'd like more attention on, a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) is probably a better option than asking another, less specific question. But no, SO isn't documentation (indeed it was tried and cancelled: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation).